# How to get Activity History when SharedActivities is enabled/disabled

Tags: soql, activityhistory, shared-activities

I execute the following query to get activity history for an account

```
  SELECT
    (SELECT Id, IsTask, ActivityDate, ActivitySubtype, Subject, Owner.Name,PrimaryWhoId,WhatId,PrimaryWho.Name, What.Name from ActivityHistories
      ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC NULLS LAST, LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT #{limit})
  FROM Account where id =
```

This works only when WhoPrimaryId exists - SharedActivities is enabled.
I use REST API.
If Shared Activities is not enabled then this query fails with error. Is there a way to determine what query to use efficiently ?

Comment: Hi, which particular error do you see ?

Comment: I get that PrimaryWhoId doesn't exist

Comment: Have you tried to use dynamic SOQL?

Comment: @GorillaAge I have posted an answer which answers your question, please accept my answer as accepted if my answer helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement this in REST API, you need two calls.

The first call to determine if `PrimaryWhoId` is available

Call `/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/ActivityHistory/describe`

and check response `fields` attributes and check if `PrimaryWhoId` is present in the list.

Then if `PrimaryWhoId` is present in the fields map, execute query

```
 SELECT
    (SELECT Id, IsTask, ActivityDate, ActivitySubtype, Subject, Owner.Name,PrimaryWhoId,WhatId,PrimaryWho.Name, What.Name from ActivityHistories
      ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC NULLS LAST, LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT #{limit})
  FROM Account where id =
```

otherwise execute

```
 SELECT
    (SELECT Id, IsTask, ActivityDate, ActivitySubtype, Subject, Owner.Name,WhoId,WhatId,Who.Name, What.Name from ActivityHistories
      ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC NULLS LAST, LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT #{limit})
  FROM Account where id =
```

Example of response

```
{
  "actionOverrides" : [ ],
  "activateable" : false,
  "childRelationships" : [ ],
  "compactLayoutable" : false,
  "createable" : false,
  "custom" : false,
  "customSetting" : false,
  "deletable" : false,
  "deprecatedAndHidden" : false,
  "feedEnabled" : false,
  "fields" : [ 

{
    "aggregatable" : true,
    "aiPredictionField" : false,
    "autoNumber" : false,
    "byteLength" : 18,
    "calculated" : false,
    "calculatedFormula" : null,
    "cascadeDelete" : false,
    "caseSensitive" : false,
    "compoundFieldName" : null,
    "controllerName" : null,
    "createable" : false,
    "custom" : false,
    "defaultValue" : null,
    "defaultValueFormula" : null,
    "defaultedOnCreate" : false,
    "dependentPicklist" : false,
    "deprecatedAndHidden" : false,
    "digits" : 0,
    "displayLocationInDecimal" : false,
    "encrypted" : false,
    "externalId" : false,
    "extraTypeInfo" : null,
    "filterable" : true,
    "filteredLookupInfo" : null,
    "formulaTreatNullNumberAsZero" : false,
    "groupable" : true,
    "highScaleNumber" : false,
    "htmlFormatted" : false,
    "idLookup" : false,
    "inlineHelpText" : null,
    "label" : "Name ID",
    "length" : 18,
    "mask" : null,
    "maskType" : null,
    "name" : "WhoId",
    "nameField" : false,
    "namePointing" : true,
    "nillable" : true,
    "permissionable" : false,
    "picklistValues" : [ ],
    "polymorphicForeignKey" : true,
    "precision" : 0,
    "queryByDistance" : false,
    "referenceTargetField" : null,
    "referenceTo" : [ "Contact", "Lead" ],
    "relationshipName" : "Who",
    "relationshipOrder" : null,
    "restrictedDelete" : false,
    "restrictedPicklist" : false,
    "scale" : 0,
    "searchPrefilterable" : false,
    "soapType" : "tns:ID",
    "sortable" : true,
    "type" : "reference",
    "unique" : false,
    "updateable" : false,
    "writeRequiresMasterRead" : false
  },
```

You need to check if there is a field with name attribute `PrimaryWhoId`.